# Best practices for drawing a planning graph diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-node

I am currently trying to represent the following diagram in tikz. However, the the representation does not have to be identically the same. I am mostly wondering about the easiest ways to build up a matrix of nodes relative to each other, where adding / removing / moving nodes is as easy as possible.

[image]

Ignoring the problems I have with spacing the nodes properly this codes mostly produces the correct result

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shapes, matrix}

\tikzset{>=stealth}

\tikzset{%
    main/.style = {},
    wait/.style = {rectangle,minimum width=0.5cm, minimum height = 0.5cm},
}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\bx}[1]{|[box, label=#1]|}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
  nodes = {node distance=10cm, anchor = center},
      continue/.style={draw, rectangle, anchor=center, node distance=10cm},
      box/.style={draw, node distance=10cm}]
  {
  BC & |[continue]| &  $\phantom{\neg}$ BC &   \\
     & |[box]|BPM   &  $\neg$ BC &  \\
     &              &  $\phantom{\neg}$ MP & \\
     & |[box]|BPM   &  &  \\
  RC & |[continue]| &  $\phantom{\neg}$ RC &  \\
     &              &  $         \neg $ RC &  \\
     &              &  &  \\
     &              &  &  \\
     & |[box]|RP    &  &  \\
  PH & |[continue]| &  $\phantom{\neg}$ PH &  \\
     &              &  $         \neg $ PH &  \\
  };

% S0 -> AO
\draw[->] (m-1-1) -- (m-1-2);
\draw[->] (m-1-1) -- (m-2-2);

\draw[->] (m-5-1) -- (m-4-2);
\draw[->] (m-5-1) -- (m-5-2);

\draw[->] (m-10-1) -- (m-9-2);
\draw[->] (m-10-1) -- (m-10-2);

% AO
\path[->] (m-1-2.south) edge [bend left=90,looseness=1] (m-2-2.north);
\path[->] (m-5-2.north) edge [bend left=90,looseness=1] (m-4-2.south);
\path[->] (m-9-2.south) edge [bend left=90,looseness=1] (m-10-2.north);

% A0 -> S1
\draw[->] (m-1-2) -- (m-1-3);
\draw[->] (m-2-2) -- (m-2-3);
\draw[->] (m-2-2) -- (m-3-3);

\draw[->] (m-5-2) -- (m-5-3);
\draw[->] (m-4-2) -- (m-6-3);
\draw[->] (m-4-2) -- (m-3-3);

\draw[->] (m-10-2) -- (m-10-3);
\draw[->] (m-10-2) -- (m-11-3);

% S1
\path[-] (m-1-3.south) edge [bend left=90,looseness=1] (m-2-3.north);
\path[-] (m-6-3.north) edge [bend left=90,looseness=1] (m-5-3.south);
\path[-] (m-10-3.south) edge [bend left=90,looseness=1] (m-11-3.north);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Hower I *truly* despise using the method of creating a matrix of nodes way. Why? For one I forgot the labels in the image, adding these as separate nodes at the top would result in me having to recalculate all the paths.

Ignoring this, this method is not suited for modifications at all. If I were to move one node, I would have recalculate every path, and getting the spacing correct is a huge pain.

Assume that I do label every point in the matrix. Now the arrows will update when I move points around, however now the spacing between nodes will be unbalanced. Which, I want to try to avoid.

Now the problem is that I many more rows and columns in that diagram, which I do not quite know *where* to place. For a general idea of my end goal is a diagram that resembles the following

https://github.com/oyvindrobertsen/TDT4136/blob/master/ex6/gardenplanning.pdf

Note however. The image above is the solution to a similar, but not identical planning diagram. I have also tried to use relative position to create the desired outcome, alas this was a futile attempt.

Comment: I don't really know what you want here. It sounds as if you'd be better off naming the nodes yourself according to their purpose. Then the paths will still connect the same nodes, even after you insert nodes shifting their relative positions in the matrix. Or use the graph syntax and/or graph drawing stuff, I guess. But you don't really seem to want an automatic solution: you want a solution which can read your mind. I'm afraid Ti*k*Z is not able to do that yet. Or I've misunderstood - as I say, I don't really know what specific thing you want to do.

Comment: To clarify the above comment, you can assign a custom name to a node (overwriting the default `m-row-col`) by putting it next to the styling information, like `|[box] (BPM-1)| BPM`. Since your custom name isn't relative to the matrix, it won't change when the node is moved.

Comment: Also, if the issue with using relative positioning is alignment, note that you can specify the coordinate horizontally aligned with coordinate `x` and vertically aligned with coordinate `y` using the syntax  `(x |- y)` or `(y -| x)`.